# Is it possible to make shortcodes NOT case sensitive?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I was wondering if it is possible to make shortcode not case sensitive, should be pretty straight forward but I want:

```
[test=1]
```

to work while written as

```
[TeST=1], [TEST=1]
```

And if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another simple idea for a *case-insensitive* shortcode:

```
/**
 * Make a shortcode case insensitive via the the_content filter
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return string $content
 */
function my_case_insensitive_shortcode( $content )
{
    $sc   = 'test'; // Edit this shortcode name to your needs

    $from = '['. $sc ; 
    $to   = $from;

    if( stristr( $content, $from ) )    
        $content = str_ireplace( $from, $to, $content );

    return $content;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_case_insensitive_shortcode', 10 );
```

You could also use `preg_replace()`, if you need more accurate replacements.

### Example:

Writing this in the post editor

```
[test id="1"]

[tEsT id="2"]

[TeSt id="3"]
```

gives the following output before the `do_shortcode` filter is activated with priority `11`:

```
[test id="1"]

[test id="2"]

[test id="3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a shortcode you've created yourself, you'd have to register all possibilities of case.

If you want all shortcodes to be case-insensitive, you'd have to modify the shortcode handling code in the Wordpress core includes (or override it I guess...)

This question [Are shortcodes case-sensitive?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102375/are-shortcodes-case-sensitive) has some info on the necessary functions you'd have to modify.

Comment: I should be fine with just one shortcode that will be not case sensitive, I got: add_shortcode( webinar, webinarShortcode );  
so do I add all cases in ( webinar, WEBINAR, WeBinAR, webinarShortcode ); or do I have to make the shortcode a bunch of times? Because that wouldn't really be an option.

Comment: You'll have to call add_shortcode() multiple times, but you can call it with the same function you've already created so add_shortcode('tEst', 'test-function'); add_shortcode('teSt', 'test-function'); should do it

Comment: @birgire 's solution seems a lot more elegant than mine - I'd choose that one! :) Mine is more of a hack!